# convertir array a json

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo este array

> var arreglo=[4,5,7,80,4,52,15,5];

y quiero convertirlo a este formato

> ```
> [
>  [[2.0924907914914139, 2.3946516145034309], 1],
>  [[2.4682273904177849, 1.6516482666336787], 1],
>  [[1.9754558657999959, 1.9355779157529831], 1],
>  [[2.082637117528451, 2.1142405395800332], 1]
> ]
> ```

por lo tanto seria:

> ```
> [
>  [[4, 5], 1],
>  [[7, 80], 1],
>  [[4, 52], 1],
>  [[15, 5], 1]
> ]
> ```

se puede insertar en un arreglo este tipo de datos, me refiero insertar un entero y un arreglo?

Comment: Si, claro que se puede. Por favor, agregar el código que tengas hecho así podemos ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo tenes, un arreglo con cierta cantidad PAR de elementos (8 en el ejemplo que das), y queres juntar estos elementos en grupos de a 2, en otro arreglo.
A su vez, al arreglo que contiene a cada par, lo queres meter dentro de otro, que tiene un segundo elemento de valor = 1.

En definitiva, podes recorrer el arreglo, ir tomando los valores de a pares, y ubicarlos en un arreglo resultante:

```js
var arreglo=[4,5,7,80,4,52,15,5];
var retorno = new Array();
arreglo.forEach(function(currentValue,index,arr) {
    if(index % 2 == 0 && arreglo.length > (index + 1)) //Me quedo solo con las posiciones pares, que tengan un elemento delante.
    {
        retorno.push([[arreglo[index], arreglo[index + 1]], 1]);
    }
});
```